# What is the meaning of $\flat$ and $\sharp$ in this smoothing operator? $M^\sharp(x,\xi)=\sum_k \Psi_0(2^{-k\delta}D)m_k(x)\;\psi_{k+1}(\xi) $

Tags: differential-geometry, operator-theory, hodge-theory, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

I found this:

$$M(x,\xi) = M^\sharp(x,\xi)+M^\flat(x,\xi),$$

in [this paper](http://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/files/2018/04/micro2.pdf), where

$$M^\sharp(x,\xi)=\sum_k \Psi_0(2^{-k\delta}D)m_k(x)\;\psi_{k+1}(\xi) $$

and i'm not sure whether i understand it correctly

Is the $\sharp$ the isomorphism $T^*M \to TM$ and $\flat$ the opposite?

Also feel free to recommend any good books of Microlocal Analysis/$\Psi DO$ if you know any.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just the author's preferred symbols for the two different pieces of $M$ (as opposed to e.g. $M(x,\xi) = M_1(x, \xi)+M_2(x,\xi)$)?

Comment: That could be the case, although i don't feel qualified neither to prove or disprove that.

Comment: I think @StevenStadnicki is right. Moreover, if $M^{\sharp}$ is defined, then $M^{\flat} = M - M^{\sharp}$ is defined.

Comment: @DIdier_ you mean if i figure out $M^\flat$ then i can check whether it works as i proposed?

Comment: No, I meant that $M^{\sharp}$ is defined (you even wrote it). Then the equality $M = M^{\sharp} + M^{\flat}$ says that $M^{\flat}$ is uniquely defined to be $M - M^{\sharp}$.

Comment: Ohh, i see! Makes sense!